# Changing a Frame from an original window to another

Tags: python, tkinter, undefined

I have this function that is generating a button every time another function is called and placing the new button into a new window. I've successfully implemented this code into my main program except for one part, the buttons will not generate in any other window except my main window. The code is a little bit longer, so I apologize.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from pathlib import Path

def window2():
    editor = tk.Toplevel()
    editor.title("Window 2")
    
def add_buttons(*items):
    for item in items:
        auto_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text=item)
        auto_button.grid(column=1)

def get_items(path):
    if path.exists():
        with open(path, "r") as f:
            data = f.read().strip().splitlines()
            return data
    return []

def save_items(path, items):
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write("\n".join(items))

def submit():
    global items

    # get the text and append it to our global list of button text
    text = entry.get()
    items.append(text)

    # create the button
    add_buttons(text)

    # save the list of items
    save_items(path, items)

root = tk.Tk()
button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
entry = tk.Entry(root)
submit = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit)

entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
submit.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
button_frame.grid(column=1)

window2_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Take me to window 2", command=window2).grid(row=2, column=0,)

# initialize our list of buttons from a file
path = Path("buttons.txt")
items = get_items(path)
add_buttons(*items)

root.mainloop()
```

I've tested this in 3 different programs now, all with the same pattern of the button properly operating in the main startup window, but won't allow me to call the function to operate in a different window as seen above in button_frame = tk.Frame(window). The code above is almost verbatim Bryan Oakley's, credit to him, I went back into the code sample he sent me to show my minimal with the same error. Each time this function is called it gives a undefined (window in this exmaple) error. I know this can't be a hard fix but for the love of me I haven't be able to figure it out.

Comment: you can certainly remove a few functions from the example such as the ones that read files and stuff, please provide a [mre], besides what is `window2` function doing exactly? it just creates a new `Tk` instance (which shouldn't be done anyways) and then destroys it, also it would raise an error because `Tk` is not defined

Comment: @Matiiss Can I though? I sort of assume that's wherein the problem lays. My issue isn't putting a button in a separate window it's this particular program generating buttons in a separate window. It's using the entry in root, to save to a text document, to pull from and generate buttons in a different window. If I pull out the read/write files then I'll just be attempting to put a button in a separate window basically.

Comment: @Matiiss Window 2 is just supposed to be a window for the buttons to generate into. How else would I create a window other than calling a window to be created and why would that be a bad thing? That's a genuine question, I'm still fairly new to this. And is tk not defined in the import?

Comment: You should only ever create a single instance of `Tk`. If you need multiple windows, the second and subsequent windows should be instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Alright. I've seen you use it before but I'm not familiar with it. I'm going to close this out as technically that will have changed my question and require a new thread. I do see now where Tk() is the incorrect way to create a 2nd window though.

Comment: Unfortunately, the official tkinter docs seem to assume you already know tcl/tk, and in that context having two root windows is very foreign. However, widgets exist in a tree, and that tree has a single root. When you create multiple root windows you create multiple trees with widgets that can't interact with each other.

Comment: @BryanOakley I like that analogy. So, using it in a TopLevel would be similar to a branch, connected to root, but it's own window to interact with? I've also changed my command to TopLevel() for window and I'm still getting either button_frame or window as undefined depending on where I put it. Not ready to officially ask a question on it yet as I'm still reading through some times and listening to someone explain the command, but it doesn't make since to me as to why it would be an undefined error and not some other error. In my head undefined is calling them out of order is it not?

Comment: _"So, using it in a TopLevel would be similar to a branch, connected to root, but it's own window to interact with?"_ - yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete script. This code works!

```
from pathlib import Path
import tkinter as tk

def window2():
    window.deiconify()
    window.lift()
    window.title("Window 2")
    window.focus_force()
    
def add_buttons(*items):
    for item in items:
        auto_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text=item)
        auto_button.grid(column=1)

def get_items(path):
    if path.exists():
        with open(path, "r") as f:
            data = f.read().strip().splitlines()
            return data
    return []

def save_items(path, items):
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write("\n".join(items))

def submit():
    global items

    # get the text and append it to our global list of button text
    text = entry.get()
    items.append(text)

    # create the button
    add_buttons(text)

    # save the list of items
    save_items(path, items)

root = tk.Tk()
window = tk.Toplevel()

button_frame = tk.Frame(window)
entry = tk.Entry(root)
submit = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit)

entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
submit.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
button_frame.grid(column=1)

window2_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Take me to window 2", command=window2).grid(row=2, column=0,)

# initialize our list of buttons from a file
path = Path("buttons.txt")
items = get_items(path)
add_buttons(*items)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried those, I'm still getting an error as either window is undefined or tkinter has no attribute frame. I'm thinking at this point it might be best to scrap this code because I'm not finding a way to do quite what I want and I feel like I should be attempting to do this through my database anyways

Comment: I have your code working by using these changes. When I rerun the code all buttons created are restored.

Comment: I'll post the entire script, maybe I missed something.

Comment: You're entirely correct, I compared yours to mine, I had a syntax error when I reran it and had an order of operations error. I greatly appreciate the help